# Вывод из базы данных php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Знаю , что наверно буду объяснять непонятно ,ну вообщем. У меня возникла проблема с базой.В базе есть две таблицы заголовки и аккумуляторы.Мне нужно в цикле пробежаться, взять первый заголовок ,потом пока не пробежится и не проверит условие , он не перейдёт в следующему элементу в первом цикле , вообще я пытался сделать как то так.

```
 <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)):; ?>
    <tr>
    <th style="height:50px;" onclick="anichange(<?php echo $row1[0]; ?>)"  colspan="5"><?php echo $row1[0]; ?></th>
    </tr>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)):;?>    
<?php if($row[0] == $row1[0]) { ?>
 <tr class="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
                <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
            </tr>   
        <? } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Соберите данные из базы заранее в массивы, а потом создавайте таблицу на основе этих данных.

Comment: vp_arth , а информация в массиве будет обновляться ,ведь у меня база для прайса ,который будет меняться каждую неделю ,нужно будет добавлять новую информацию в базу.

Comment: Нет, соберите **данные из базы** в массив. Т.е. прогоните полные циклы с fetch, собирая нужные данные. У вас получится 2 массива, с заголовками и с что там у вас ещё. Потом ходите по этим массивам и стройте таблицу. По крайней мере заголовки совершенно точно нужно получить заранее(потому что они вам нужны и в шапке, и в теле таблицы)

Comment: vp_arth, дело в том что ключевую роль играет не вывод заголовка на экран а его имя ,как я его получу если создам массив .Можешь показать на примере.

Comment: @SemyonDyachenko, приведите структуру таблиц БД  (с тестовыми данными) и сами запросы, которыми вы эти данные получаете. Судя по приведенному в вопросе коду, мне кажется, можно все свести к одному запросу и одному циклу.